# Most likely error with Hamming distance

Tags: error-correcting-codes

I have a basic question about Hamming distances, something confuse me in the book I'm reading about it.

Let's assume we have a codeword $y$ that received an error $e$. Thus we had the following event:

$$ y_0 \rightarrow y'=y_0+e $$

In Nielsen & Chuang, page 449, he says:

> Provided the probability of a bit flip is less than 1/2, the most
>   likely codeword to have been encoded is the codeword y which minimizes
>   the number of bit flips needed to get from y to y',that is,which
>   minimizes wt(e)= d(y, y').

Where $d(a,b)$ is the Hamming distance between $a$ and $b$, and $wt(e)$ is the Hamming weight of $e$, which is $d(e,0)$.

My question is the following:

I agree that if there is more probability of no bit flip than the probability to have one, then the most likely codeword is the closest one from $y'$, thus a codeword $y$ minimising $d(y,y')$.

However, as he writes $d(y,y')=wt(e)$, he seems to assume that the closest vector from $y'$ is necesseraly the one we encoded. Which for me is not true in general, the error could have put us closer to another encoded word than the one we encoded right ?

Where is my misunderstanding here ?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your question but I feel you have possibly answered your own question. The part that you agree with is equivalent to what you have problem with. Since you agree that y minimizes distance over all the codewords isn't that same the statement?

Comment: @Root I can reformulate my question as: why do we have $d(y,y')=wt(e)$ ? Why is it equal to the rhs. For me it is not obvious. I hope it is more clear now =)

Comment: Now if I understand things right your question is why  $y-y'=e$?

Comment: @Root Yes that's it. For me it is only true if $y$ was the originally encoded message $y_0$ but I could expect it as not being true in general

Comment: If $y$ is different from $y_0$ and $y_0$ is closer to $y'$ than $y$ then that is contradicting with the part you agree with.

Comment: @Root I could have $d(y,y') < d(y_0,y')$ Thus I would interpret $y \neq y_0$ as being the encoded message which is not true. And as $d(y',y_0)=wt(e)$ I don't have $d(y,y')=wt(e)$

Comment: Then $d(y,y_0)$ by triangle inequality is at most $2e$ but any two codewords have minimum distance $2e+1$. Does that answer your problem?

Comment: @Root did you want to talk about $d(y,y')$ instead of $d(y,y_0)$ ? I don't understand why you say it is at most $2e$. Also why do you say any two codewords have minimum distance $2e+1$ ? Don't you add some assumption to the problem to say so ? If I take an $[3,2]$ code, I could imagine one codeword being $(100)$ and another one being $(110)$.

Comment: Isn't $e$ decodable error? I think I am talking about right codewords. my idea is to show that y is same as $y_0$ by showing that they are too close to be codewords.  Then if $d$ is minimum distance of code then $wt(e) \leq \lfloor (d-1)/2 \rfloor$ $d(y,y_0) \leq d(y,y') + d(y',y_0)$ each of which is less than $wt(e)$ giving contradiction.